# Fazer select buscando os 3 maiores valores

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela que tem os seguintes dados:

> **id_indication, id_user,lg_cliente**

Um usuário pode indicar vários clientes **(lg_cliente = 1)**, gostaria de um select que buscasse os 3 usuários que mais indicaram,ou seja, os três **id_user** que tenham mais **lg_cliente = 1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se isto resolve seu problema

```
select * from TABELA order by lg_cliente DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: retorna: error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3 * from tb_indication order by lg_cliente DESC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: tente assim
select * from TABELA order by lg_cliente DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Mesmo erro: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3 * from tb_indication

Comment: Pode me mandar como ficou o comando que você esta colocando no sql

Comment: select TOP 3 * from tb_indication order by lg_cliente DESC

Comment: tente como coloquei acima select * from TABELA order by lg_cliente DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Dessa forma ele busca os 3 primeiros onde lg_cliente = 1, e não necessariamente os 3 que tem mais lg_cliente = 1

Comment: Bia, na verdade no comando ele ordena em ordem decrescente então os primeiros registros sempre serão os maiores. Verifique se em sua tabela possui registros com mais de 1 na coluna lg_cliente

Comment: Eu entendi, mas com esse sql ele me retorna o seguinte:
id_user: 1,1,34.
Ou seja ele pega o mesmo id duas vezes, gostaria de buscar os 3 maiores de usuários diferentes.

Comment: Tem certeza que você não tem esse usuário repetido no banco, pois este select não deveria duplicar as informações ele apenas mostra as que tem acesso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33680/discussion-between-antonio-raichaski-and-bia).

Comment: O id repete sim, pois nessa tabela tb_indication, um mesmo usuário pode indicar um cliente várias vezes

Comment: select * from TABELA group by id_user order by SUM(lg_cliente) DESC LIMIT 3. Resolveu o problema.